# Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Getting error Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange. from this code.

```js
if (returnForm.getRange(12, 4).isBlank()) {
        returnFormUI.alert("Not allowed.")
    } else {...
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's this piece of script? The error message talks about `null` and a number. There's no `null` in the script in your question.

Comment: @Andreas what do you suggest then?

Comment: @SamWard, it would be better if you could provide an executable script so we could test out the issue ourselves. the code above should not cause any error.